# Quelles seraient d’autres façons plus standards de dire « laisser retomber la poussière »?

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques, formulation-idiomatique, reformulation

Choisissez le bon moment. Dans la mesure du possible, allez-y spontanément, si la personne offensée vous est très proche. Il est parfois plus utile de régler rapidement un conflit. Mais certains psychologues suggèrent plutôt de **laisser retomber la poussière**, le temps pour les deux parties de rationaliser la situation, surtout s’il y a de la colère dans l’air.

Comment: Tu cherches changer de registre ou des expressions idiomatiques ? Qu'est-ce que tu as trouvé qui ne convient pas ?  Prendre une pause ou un moment par exemple ?

Comment: Une expression moins figurée pourrais-je dire.

Comment: Mais disons, pour répondre à ta question, un mélange des deux, un registre moins familier et une expression idiomatique.

Comment: Autre que « laisser passer l’orage », qui a aussi une saveur figurée…

Comment: — « Laisser le temps au temps. » — Sinon, selon le contexte : « Ne pas tomber dans le panneau [des solutions toutes faites | du miroir aux alouettes | … ]. » « Prends ton temps, il n'y a pas urgence ! » « On ne décide rien sous la colère / la colère est mauvaise conseillère » …

Comment: @Personne Je m’attendais plutôt à quelque chose qui se rapprochait de « attendre qu’une situation devienne moins risquée, attendre la fin d’un conflit ».

Comment: Comme dans « Avec tout ce qu’on entend aux nouvelles concernant « Bombardier » comme les scandales, la chute de l’action et les licenciements, je vais attendre que la situation devienne moins risquée (je vais laisser passer l’orage/je vais laisser retomber la poussière) avant de poser ma candidature et préserver mon emploi estudiantin. »

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On peut se rabattre sur un verbe de sens figuré, et qui ne connote  de figuré en tant qu'expression que ce qu'une possible évocation du sens littéral peut continuer à insinuer chez le lecteur ; comble de la contradiction vis-à-vis du but recherché, ce sens littéral décrit un processus très précisément similaire à celui de la poussière qui retombe puisque il s'agit du processus de la décantation.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9canter)) **décanter**  **2.** *Au fig.* Clarifier, mettre de l'ordre (dans), dégager les éléments essentiels (de).
> • Les souffrances d'amour (...) décantent nos sentiments (Barrès, Jard. Bérén.,1891, p. 109)
> • Le recul que me donnait maintenant mon voyage aux Syrtes me dotait d'une clairvoyance plus grande : le souvenir décantait à distance des impressions jusque-là sans cesse brassées et dissoutes dans ce tumulte du quotidien qui nous ramène à flot dans son agitation légère. Gracq, Le Riuage des Syrtes,1951, p. 59.

- Choisissez le bon moment. Dans la mesure du possible, allez-y spontanément, si la personne offensée vous est très proche. Il est parfois plus utile de régler rapidement un conflit. Mais certains psychologues suggèrent plutôt de *décanter* la querelle, le temps pour les deux parties de rationaliser la situation, surtout s’il y a de la colère dans l’air.

« Le temps pour les deux parties de rationaliser la situation » n'est qu'une reprise de cette idée de « laisser retomber la poussière », qui est maintenant considérée relativement aux deux partis, une idée qui ne serait  pas dans le contexte de ce paragraphe celle d'un processus laissé à lui-même, c'est à dire dans lequel n'intervient pas la participation active des protagonistes (l'oubli ou l'attente), mais au contraire une véritable action  (rationaliser),  tout au moins de la part du protagoniste à qui sont proférés les conseils. Je ne vois pas d'autre explication possible : l'idée que l'on conseillerait à  la personne que l'on avise de  laisser faire le temps et rien de plus n'est pas logique ; c'est pourtant un sens que l'on peut donner à « laisser retomber la poussière ».